# Android Instrumented tests fail when all run together

Tags: android, testing, ui-testing, android-espresso

I am running Android instrumented tests using espresso.

I have a little more than 70 tests to be run which all click through different parts of my application.

When I run each test as a single test they all work and I get a green test result.

When I run them all at the same time (right click on the androidTest folder -> hit run) then some of them fail saying the view cannot be found.

In different runs different tests are failing. I think it might be that something is going too quickly here.

Do you guys have any suggestions on how to fix this?
Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in [Setup your test environment](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/setup/#setup-your-test-environment) section of [Espresso setup instructions](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/setup/) you have:

> On your device, under Settings->Developer options disable the following 3 settings:
>
> Window animation scale
>
> Transition animation scale
>
> Animator duration scale

animations may be related with your suspicion: *something is going too quickly here*

you may also use `Thread.sleep(1000);` (milliseconds) inside test methods for delaying some calls

anyway, without any code all above its just a guess...

Comment: thanks. turning off animations did not do much. Inserting pauses helps to make it more stable. But not really 100%. It also makes my tests soooo slow.
Can you hint me towards some kind of code that I can post that would help understand the project? Because how I see it I just have a lot of different UI tests each doing different things and crashing at different times. -> I will investigate further and see if I can find a pattern which tests exactly are failing and under what conditions.
Thanks again!